# Changing html5 canvas buffer size and webgl

Tags: canvas, webgl

Changing html5 canvas buffer size i.e. canvas.width and canvas.height seems to change the canvas display dimentions on ios 8 and ios 9 when using webgl, in desktop browsers seems to be ok:
https://jsfiddle.net/psqvur80/

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="iv" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iv = document.getElementById('iv');

    var test = function(){
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.canvas.style.width = '100%';
        this.canvas.style.height = '100%';
        this.canvas.width = 200;
        this.canvas.height = 200;
        this.canvas.style.borderColor = 'red';
        this.canvas.style.borderWidth = '2px';
        this.canvas.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        iv.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.initWebGL();

    }

    test.prototype.initWebGL = function() {
        // attempt to get a webgl context
        try {
            var gl = this.gl = this.canvas.getContext('webgl') || this.canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }


    };

    var testcase = new test();

    testcase.gl.viewport(0, 0, 200, 200);
    testcase.gl.clearColor(0, 0.5, 0, 1);
    testcase.gl.clear(testcase.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    setTimeout(function(){
        //console.log('resize');
        testcase.gl.viewport(0, 0, 100, 100);
        testcase.canvas.width = 100;
        testcase.canvas.height = 100;

        testcase.gl.clearColor(0, 0.5, 0, 1);
        testcase.gl.clear(testcase.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }, 2000);



</script>               
</body>
```

I tried viewport settings, but with no luck.
How can I keep the display dimentions while changing buffer size of the canvas ?

Answer (score 1):

sigh ... looks like a bug in iOS Safari. [Filed a bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=152556)

I haven't found a direct workaround yet. One crappy workaround is to change the size of the container for a moment.

```
iv.style.width = "401px";
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  iv.style.width = "400px";
});
```

I think I haven't noticed this issue since I always make the canvas the same size as it's being displayed.

Is there some reason your use case requires the canvas to be smaller? It's clearly a bug in Safari. Just asking if you can work around it

Comment: nice one, the image dimentions that are in sequence sometimes change and so canvas needs to, I wonder if computation wise this method is better than re-creating the canvas itself which should not trigger layout change.